# Graph/Chart - How do you change the bar fill colour?

Tags: excel, vba

Think I'm getting closer to getting the correct code, but I can't figure it out.

This line specifically is what is giving me the error:

```
wsSLSummary.ChartObjects("CLoans").FullSeriesCollection("Sum of Market Value").Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(36, 7, 249)
```

I'm just trying to simply change the fill colour of the bars in the series. I have multiple graphs on the same worksheet so I've named them, "CLoans" is an example.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be a `.Chart` after `("CLoans")` IIRC.

Comment: You. Are. A. Genius. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Ben - think you've helped me a couple of times, was wondering, how did you know that .chart was needed there? Is there a way you go about debugging errors? I want to learn this, I never would have figured that out in a million years. ty! @BigBen

Comment: The fact that it's [`Chart.FullSeriesCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.fullseriescollection) in the docs helped.